# KDE system monitor vs GNOME system monitor

Tags: linux, gnome, kde, system-monitoring

I have both the system monitors of KDE and GNOME. When I compare the CPU usage of a CPU intensive program, that of KDE reports a 30% usage and 3GB of memory while that of GNOME reports 300% of CPU and same -3Gbs - of memory!

So, my questions:

1. Why they reported different CPU usage for the same program while they reported the same memory usage?
2. What is the meaning of 300% CPU usage that GNOME system monitor reports?!

---

**System Info:** Redhat 6.6 (Santiago) - **Kernel:** (Linux 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64) - 
**GNOME:** 2.28.2 -
**KDE:** 4.3.4

Comment: When a process is using more than a core you can have value like that. (`100%*3=300%`). It's strange however even for different ways to report it. Did you check it with `top`? ps> Welcome (out) on __SuperUser__. Is the test made with the same program doing the same things and with the same `nice`? Moreover, are the monitors showing the same quantity?

Comment: I guess you are right, maybe KDE shows CPU usage out of all available cores. `top` produces same result as GNOME monitor. yes I run the program and have both monitors running at the same time.

Comment: There are many different _applets_ that will work as _system monitors_. If you refer to some of them, maybe you should add a link to their homepage. BTW check for what they are showing. (Maybe there is the possibility to select overall CPU usage or something else...). PS> with `top` you can press `1` and open the single core usage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CPU usage: cumulative vs average value.

A modern CPU has multiple cores.
If you have a process that is using intensively 3 cores it can be reported to use *"300% of CPU usage"*, its cumulative value, as well as that value divided by the number of cores.

Sometimes it is more useful the first, some other the second. Often it is possible to choose as option.

Under KDE, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>, it starts the System Activity <sup>[[1](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Activity)]</sup>

> that is akin to the Microsoft Windows' Task Manager, Apple's Mac OS X's Activity Monitor and Gnome's System Monitor.

Stopping the cursor over one of the CPU values shown, you will see a mask with some information more.

[image]

If you right click on the bar were is written USERNAME, CPU... over **CPU** it will be open a pull-down menu with the possibility to divide the CPU Value shown (cpu usage) for the number of CPUs (core), or to show the full value.

Comment: and actually if you press right click over **CPU** tab, you can choose to show the average or the cumulative.

Comment: `:-)` Ok, it's better to specify. On memory it gives even more options. For each column there are (or not) specific options.